# Replace Word line break from sentence range do not work

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I have a application where I want to get the first line of the word content to automatically set a title for a document to save it.

I do this:

```
  if (WordApp != null)
  {
    FileName = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Name;
    // get the content from the first available text as filename
    if (IsNewRecord && WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count > 0 )
      FileName = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Sentences.First.Text;
  }
```

Nevertheless it works, but the `FileName` also contains the `LineBreak` for the first sentence.

So I tried:

```
.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
```

But did not do anything, neither `"\n"`.

Anyone know what I do wrong or how to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Thank for the feedback. In fact \v works for line break. Now I realize that I also have to take care about the paragraph. I still get a "next line" from the paragraph.

Comment: Put your comments to answer section so I can set it as answer, your tips helped me to get the issue solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Word *line break* (e.g. that you can insert using shift-Enter on Windows Word) is represented by ASCII character 11, so you can look for that in C#, e.g. using \v .

A Word *paragraph mark* is represented by ASCII character 13, which you may be able to find using \r, at least on Windows.

The characters do not vary between Windows and Mac (and, I assume the online platforms). i.e. the paragraph mark is always 13 (CR), never 10 (LF), even on Unix-based systems.